# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded TeamCity 7.0

Tags: windows, java, teamcity, tomcat7

I am getting this error suddenly.  Running teamcity 7.0 on a Windows Server 2008.  How do I add more memory via passing options to the JVM?  I don't understand how to pass the xmx option when using teamcity with java.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to cd to the TeamCity home directory /bin/x64/tomcat7w.exe and run //ES//teamcity which opens the settings for tomcat, then click the Java tab.